# MySQL query runtime in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, datatable

Good morning, I am trying to execute a mysql query in php that brings me a certain amount of data and paints it in a datatable, I already tried the query in Mysql and it takes 1: 35s trallendo all the data, this delay is because it is a very large amount of data, the question is that when executing this query in php it generates an error 500 (Internal Server Error) and I tried with set_time_limit (0); to increase the execution time of the query php ´but still it does not work any one knows or has had this error.
my code is the following

```
<?php
include("conexion_oracle.php");



$proceso = $_POST['proceso'];


 if ($proceso === "repor_actividad") {
    set_time_limit(0);
        $fech_ini = $_POST['fech_ini'];
         $fech_fin = $_POST['fech_fin'];

if ($fech_ini !== "" && $fech_fin !== "") {
      $filtro_fech = "AND EPIINAFEN BETWEEN TO_DATE('$fech_ini 00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('$fech_fin 23:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')";
 } else {
$filtro_fech = "AND EPIINAFEN BETWEEN TO_DATE('19000101 00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('19000101 23:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')";
    }
if ($proceso === "repor_actividad") {
    set_time_limit(0);
        $fech_ini = $_POST['fech_ini'];
         $fech_fin = $_POST['fech_fin'];

if ($fech_ini !== "" && $fech_fin !== "") {
      $filtro_fech = "AND EPIINAFEN BETWEEN TO_DATE('$fech_ini 00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('$fech_fin 23:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')";
 } else {
$filtro_fech = "AND EPIINAFEN BETWEEN TO_DATE('19000101 00:01', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') AND TO_DATE('19000101 23:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')";
    }
  $reporActivi = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT CIANOM AS SEDE,
    EPIINAHIS AS ID_UNICO,
    EPIINANUM AS INGRESO,
    EPIINATEP AS TIPO_DE_ATENCION,
    EPIINADDX AS DIAGNOSTICO
FROM HIEPIINA
INNER JOIN ABPAC ON EPIINAHIS = PACHIS
  $filtro_fech");

     oci_execute($reporActivi);
    $ex_datos = 0;
    while ($data = oci_fetch_array($reporActivi, OCI_ASSOC)) {
        $arreglo["data"][] = $data;
        $ex_datos = 1;
    }

    if ($ex_datos === 1) {

        echo json_encode($arreglo, true);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("data" => ""));
    }
    oci_free_statement($reporActivi);
```

and my js code is as follows

```
 var table = $("#tb_activ_medic").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            method: "POST",
            url: "../../consultas_repor_jefatura.php",
            data: { "proceso": "repor_actividad", "fech_ini": fech_ini, "fech_fin": fech_fin },
        },
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        lengthMenu: [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "Todo"]
        ],
        buttons: [
            'excel'
        ],
        order: [
            [0, "asc"]
        ],
        bDestroy: true,
        columns: [

            { data: "SEDE", title: "SEDE" },

            { data: "EMPRESA", title: "EMPRESA" },
            { data: "ACTIVIDAD_REALIZADA", title: "ACTIVIDAD REALIZADA" },
            { data: "FECHA_HORA_INICIO_ACTIVIDAD", title: "FECHA HORA INICIO ACTIVIDAD" },

        ],
        language: idioma
    });
```

Comment: You probably have a syntax error. Have you checked the PHP errors logs? The code in your question is clearly incomplete, so I can't tell whether the error is in that part or somewhere else.

Comment: I just completed all the php code and added the js in which I call it the php process, sistancis error is not since I have made this same code for several queries that take either 20 or 30 seconds to execute the subject is the execution time of this query which is between 1:30 to 1:40 depending on the time period

Comment: Well, that may be so, but an error 500 means the server cannot execute the PHP code. In all cases I had this error there was an error message in the logs and it almost always is a syntax error.

Comment: I have checked the PHP logs and I cannot find a syntax error, what seems strange to me is that if I run the query with a 3-day date range, it runs correctly, but if I increase the days, the error 500 is generated, I think I have I have to put the MYsql query execution time but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Ah, yes, having a time-out is the same as not being able to run the PHP code. The time limit is probably just the default PHP limit, see: [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: if I put the timeout so that the mysql query can perform and take as long as necessary, but since php has a 30 second time limit for queries, it doesn't run such a large query for me.

Comment: Then you have to extend the time your queries are allowed to run. This is probably not a PHP issue, but rather a database issue.

Comment: it cannot be a database problem since the query if executed in the MYSQl console only it takes 1: 30s to complete

Comment: You're confusing me. You're talking about a MySQL console, and you compare that with PHP in which I can see [Oracle OCI8 functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php). I would normally expect the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) interface to MySQL. I don't know anything about time-outs and OCI8.